# Code=-11850 "Operation Stopped"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play video on iphone device it is not working, but this video is worked on the web browser.

this is the streaming link
http://dinamalar.bc.cdn.bitgravity.com/video/mob/News_27_Knnaiah_06032016.mp4. if i am using this link. i am getting empty black screen.

this is my code,

```
NSString *mediafilepath = @"http://dinamalar.bc.cdn.bitgravity.com/video/mob/News_27_Knnaiah_06032016.mp4";
NSString *urlString = [mediafilepath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
moviePlayer.view.frame = rectTemp;
moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:moviePlayer];
[scrollView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

If the video plays on your desktop machine, but not iOS (either in-app or in Safari), it's most likely because the HTTP server does not support byte-range requests. If the HTTP server does not support byte-range requests, iOS will not play the video. This differs from Safari on OS X, which plays the video regardless.

From the Safari Documentation:

> HTTP servers hosting media files for iOS must support byte-range requests, which iOS uses to perform random access in media playback.
>   (Byte-range support is also known as content-range or partial-range
>   support.) Most, but not all, HTTP 1.1 servers already support
>   byte-range requests.

Also, the HTTP server must provide a valid Content-Type header (the URL above also enumerates the valid MIME types). iOS will not play the video if the MIME type is invalid or missing.